# Unable to embed media for the second time

Tags: ckeditor, fckeditor

I am unable to Embed media for CKEditor when an Emded media already exist. I mean if i have already put a video on the page and saved it, then when i try to edit the page again and insert another video, the embed doesnt work. Nothing happens when i click on OK after pasting the Embed code in the Embed Dialog box that pops up when i click on the embed media icon.
Any ideas as to what might be going wrong?

Comment: The firebug console gives the error 

Permission denied for <example.com> to get property Window.name

Any idea what to do?

Comment: some cross domain stuff...  works with a try catch...

Comment: Any resolution for this?